# where does the wireshark capture the packets

Tags: networking, wireshark

where does the wireshark capture the packets in the linux kernel? If an output packet is captured by wireshark , will the packet be sent out definitely through corresponding interface?
In other words,  could an output packet that captured by wireshark be dropped before it is sent out?

Comment: It's captured in the network protocol stack. The packet could conceivably be dropped subsequently by the NIC, or held there indefinitely, or reported back to the kernel as unsendable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> where does the wireshark capture the packets in the linux kernel?

On UN*Xes, it uses [libpcap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap), which, on Linux, uses [AF_PACKET sockets](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/packet.7.html).  (On Windows, it uses WinPcap, which is a driver plus a port of libpcap to use the driver.)

> If an output packet is captured by wireshark , will the packet be sent out definitely through corresponding interface?

No.  The networking stack hands the packet to the appropriate AF_PACKET sockets and to the driver; the driver might drop the packet (for example, if, on an Ethernet, it got multiple collisions and gave up) even though the packet was delivered to the AF_PACKET socket.

> In other words, could an output packet that captured by wireshark be dropped before it is sent out?

Yes.  See above.

Comment: Hello, I'm still kind of confused how to use the AF_PACKET socket. I made a new post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37802820/where-did-wireshark-tcpdump-libpcap-intercept-packet-inside-linux-kernel. Could you please help me? Thanks!