# Where did Wireshark/tcpdump/libpcap intercept packet inside Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, wireshark

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620590/where-does-the-wireshark-capture-the-packets), wireshark is able to get the packet before it is dropped (therefore I cannot get such packets by myself). And I'm still wondering the exact location in linux kernel for wireshark to fetch the packets.

The answer goes as "On UN*Xes, it uses libpcap, which, on Linux, uses AF_PACKET sockets." Does anyone have more concrete example to use "AF_PACKET sockets"? If I understand wireshark correctly, the network interface card (NIC) will make a copy of all incoming packets and send it to a filter (berkeley packet filter) defined by the user. But where does this happen? Or am I wrong with that understanding and do I miss anything here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But where does this happen?

If I understood you correctly - you want to know, where is initialized such socket.
There is `pcap_create` [function](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/blob/master/pcap.c#L441), that tries to determine type of source interface, creates duplicate of it and activates it.
For network see `pcap_create_interface` [function](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/blob/master/pcap-linux.c#L457) => `pcap_create_common` [function](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/blob/master/pcap.c#L576) => `pcap_activate_linux` [function](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/blob/master/pcap-linux.c#L1422).
All initialization happens in `pcap_activate_linux` => `activate_new` [function](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/blob/master/pcap-linux.c#L3275) => `iface_bind` [function](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/blob/master/pcap-linux.c#L5228)
( copy descriptor of device with `handlep->device = strdup(device);`,
create socket with `socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_DGRAM, htons(ETH_P_ALL))`,
bind socket to device with `bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &sll, sizeof(sll))` ).
For more detailed information read comments in source files of mentioned functions - they are very detailed.
After initialization all work happens in a group of [functions](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/blob/master/pcap-linux.c#L1448) such as `pcap_read_linux`, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That's indeed what I want. And one more question, given this, I feel like libpcap does nothing with the kernel stuffs and is a pure user-space program. It tries to have another instance of socket and listen to it, have a copy of all packets. Am I correct for these understandings?

Comment: "I feel like libpcap does nothing with the kernel stuffs and is a pure user-space program." libpcap is a user-space library, but I'm not sure that it "does nothing with the kernel stuffs". I've briefly looked at network ( mainly ethernet ) capturing, but there are usb, bluetooth, etc. You need to check yourself code for cases that you are interested in.
"It tries to have another instance of socket and listen to it, have a copy of all packets." Yes, network ( mainly ethernet ) capturing seems to work this way.

Comment: I know this is an old thread. Just put my understanding here so it may help someone.
For the kernel stuff, you can check this post, which is very long. But it mentioned how tcpdump get the packet for the tx side. ( Rx side is different )
https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2017/02/06/monitoring-tuning-linux-networking-stack-sending-data/#linux-netdevice-subsystem
In short, for tx side tcpdump, search following code in the kernel:
       if (!list_empty(&ptype_all))
                        dev_queue_xmit_nit(skb, dev);

tcpdump will satisfy type_all check.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you should be able to simply use [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html) (which leverages the libpcap library) to do this. This can be done with a file or to STDOUT and you specify the filter at the end of the tcpdump command..

Comment: Hmmm... But after finding the packet, I also need to do sth with it (eg. drop it, modify the data, etc), tcpdump may not be able to achieve such complex tasks.

Comment: No, it cannot. You can, however do some of that with the [mangle table](http://serverfault.com/questions/467756/whats-the-mangle-table-in-iptables) of iptables, or whatever the firewalld equivelant is. If you are building more robust code, then you could see what kernel hooks it uses. You can replay packets after modification with [tcpreplay](http://tcpreplay.appneta.com/) but only for UDP or a single TCP stream.