# does packet capturng bypass part of TCP/IP stack?

Tags: tcp, wireshark, packet, packet-sniffers

When I capture network packets with `wireshark` or `tcpdump` on Linux, very often it saves segmented `TCP` which `wireashark` can reassemble (as long as Edit->Preferences->Protocols ... has this options checked for a protocol, for example HTTP).

However, I thought that the TCP/IP stack would reassemble the packets *before* delivering it to the user application, e.g. a WEB browser.

So my question is: is capturing packets bypassing some portion of TCP/IP stack?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37802820/where-did-wireshark-tcpdump-libpcap-intercept-packet-inside-linux-kernel) regarding the type of socket libpcap uses and see the description of `PF_PACKET` [here](https://www.cse.wustl.edu/~jain/cse567-11/ftp/pkt_recp/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes

Longer answer: "packet capturing" doesn't interfere with the normal packet handling -- it just makes copies of the packets at a point where they pass through the kernel.  The normal place for this to happen is between the device driver and the networking stack, but depending on how you have filtering set up, it can happen other places as well.

Comment: thanks for feedback. By "depending on how you have filtering set up" do you mean that netfilter rules can pick up packets after TCP/IP has processed them and redirect to PF_SOCKET?

Comment: It depends on your OS and the features it has enabled -- but after TCP processing, there is just a byte stream with no concept of "packets" so there's not really a "packet filtering" way to do that, but you could use ptrace to intecept what a user-level process is getting from a socket.

Comment: @Mark, if you use `netfilter` to, e.g., send packets to user space and process them with `libipq`, then you will not see fragments.   `netfilter`, like most firewalls, needs to operate on reassembled packets to usefully filter.